# Search Keyword and rename entire file using VBS

Tags: vbscript

I spent a quite a bit looking around. I did find one method that was extremely close to what I was looking for but it replaces keywords.

```
Dim sName
Dim fso
Dim fol

' create the filesystem object
 Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  ' get current folder
  Set fol = fso.GetFolder("F:\Downloads")

   ' go thru each files in the folder
   For Each fil In fol.Files
 ' check if the file name contains underscore
If InStr(1, fil.Name, "[wizardry] tv show bob - 13") <> 0 Then
' replace underscore with space
sName = Replace(fil.Name, "[wizardry] tv show bob - 13", "tv show bob S03E13")
' rename the file
fil.Name = sName
End If
Next

 ' echo the job is completed
 WScript.Echo "Completed!"
```

But as I said, the only issue is that it repalces the keywords. I want it to replace the ENTIRE file name with what I want.

Most of the files will have a group tag before hand like this: [wizardy] tv show bob - 13

I want to make sure the group tag is gone so I can actually copy the file over. Unless there is a way to pull the file name of the current file I renamed.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of replace, you need to generate a new name with the original extension, I think? If not, please give us more detail.

```
Dim sName
Dim fso
Dim fol
Dim fil
Dim ext

Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fol = fso.GetFolder("F:\Downloads")

For Each fil In fol.Files
    'may need to specify a comparison
    If InStr(1, fil.Name, "[wizardry] tv show bob - 13", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        ext = fso.GetExtensionName(fil)
        If Len(ext) > 0 Then ext = "." & ext
        sName = "tv show bob S03E13" & ext
        fil.Name = sName
    End If
Next

WScript.Echo "Completed!"
```

Comment: Ma man! Works perfectly! 

Silly question though, does the Dim lines need to be there? and what if I wanted to add more equations to the mix? (E12, E11 etc)

Thanks :D

Also, do you think there is a way to copy the file found, then paste the rename? I currently use this: 

If (objFSO.FileExists("D:\TV Shows\tv\tv show S01E02.mkv")) Then
Else
objFSO.CopyFile "D:\Downloads\[tracker] tv show - 02 [1080p].mkv", "D:\TV Shows\tv\tv show S01E02.mkv"
End If

Just wondering if it is possible, since the file comes from a torrent, it can't be renamed while still loaded in the torrent program

Comment: @dkblackhawk You're welcome. `Dim` lines are not mandatory unless you set `Option Explicit` on. See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx If the solution is worked, take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and welcome to Stack Overflow! always feel free to ask new questions, instead of asking here as "comment" :)

Comment: Ah, didn't realize I had to submit another question. That was my bad, thanks!